# Facebook events ID's order. What rule is used to enumerate the id's of events?

Tags: facebook, api, events

I've created test event which has the address like this:
www dot facebook dot com/events/1485237735028137

What mean the digits at the end?? 
How are they generated when event is created?

For example in vk dot com social network events have order: 1,2,3,4,......
And what order in Facebook?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need such information for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number at the end is the Event ID, it uniquely identifies that event, but there's no other information you can infer from that ID directly - you need to retrieve the event details via the API to get more data

Comment: Yes, I know. But I don't need more data. Just now I need to know the rule. If some event has number N which number will have the next created event?

And if such rule exists?

Comment: No, there's no information you can infer from the ID string itself, they're not assigned sequentially or with specific subsequences referring to specific object types